Get data from Quill Editor and insert it in MySQL database in Laravel 11?
I've used Quill Editor in my Laravel project. However, I am unable to retrieve the value from the editor. I tried adding a name attribute but this is not working.
<div id="content" name="content" style="height: 300px;">
  <p>Start writing here...</p>
</div>

I read a few articles about this issue but I'm not able to understand it properly.

<div> elements do not expect a name property... You're thinking <input> or other form elements (select, textarea, etc.). Please edit your question and include these articles and your code attempts. As currently written, all you've told us is "this is not working", but that's obvious for a number of reasons... Why is it not working? What specifically is happening vs what are you expecting to happen?

use <textarea /> tag with name attribute or get the content div inner data with javascript or jquery
$('#content')[0].innerHtml

